# How do you get rid of Darth Vader?

Tags: pinball-fx2

Once he spawned he is preventing you from starting any Episode and kills your ball when you shoot it in his general direction.

**How can I get rid of him without losing the Ball?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the table guide "Star Wars Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back" from one of the developers there is no way to get rid of him, he disappears after a given time. As long as he is there you can get points from him.

Copy&paste [from the guide](http://blog.zenstudios.com/press/assets/table_guides/Star_Wars_Episode_V_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_Guide_By_ShoryukenToTheChin.pdf):

> Vader Frenzy *60 or so Seconds*
>
> To start the Vader Frenzy you
>   must hit the Vader Target, each time you will collect a Letter of
>   ‘VADER’  and upon collecting all of the 5 Letters the Frenzy will
>   begin
>
> Darth Vader will then appear on the Table’s Playfield; the goal is to hit the Ball at him using the erected  Jump Ramp (located at the
>   Centre of the Table’s Playfield), each time you do that Vader will
>   crush the Ball  and you will be awarded some Points.    Repeat this as
>   many times as you can within the time limit.

Comment: For those wondering: There are very detailed guides for about every table in Pinball FX2: http://blog.zenstudios.com/?page_id=637